# AngularJS alternative to Mustache partial view usage

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mustache

I picked up a project that used Handlebars and Mustache in its views.

I want to transform and re-use most of it to AngularJS. However I'm having a problem with a simple thing: With Mustache if, for example, I have an index.html file like this:

```
<div class = "blah">
    {{>sidebar}}
</div>
```

Having a sidebar.html with the elements I want to appear. It's basically using the same partial sidebar in all the other views aswell. However, I don't know what I can use as an alternative to this.

Any suggestions using AngularJS or generic HTML are very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look into `ng-include` directive. I would probably wrap it within custom directive calles `sidebar`.

Comment: I tried that before posting the question and it didn't work. I looked a bit more into it, rearranged it a bit and still didn't work, don't know if I'm doing something wrong but I'll keep looking into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at creating your own [Angular Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), name it something like 'sidebar', which you can then call in your html ex.

```
<div class = "blah">
    <sidebar></sidebar>
</div>
```

Edit: I made a quick [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b760dg79/1/) to show you the basic principle, you can use the link I provided for more intricate details. (ex. instead of defining the template in a string, you can use the templateURL property and provide an html file as a template.

I would also recommend you passing in the state of the sidebar you want to render, rather than it sharing your parent controller state, but that is just a personal preference ( makes it easier to re-use ).

Comment: I tried that (pre-edit, will try again, thanks) and it didn't work, however it does seem like the best solution. I don't know if the fact that it is set as handlebars in the app.js file, using the extname to set it to html can cause conflicts because I tried to run a simple Angular snippet in the main page and nothing shows. Should I change that?